# Plotting by group - for many groups

Tags: stata

I want to do a graph by group. For histograms, that can be done with the option `hist ... , by(group)`. Unfortunately, stata will attempt to fit all groups on the same figure. This becomes unreadable when there is many groups.

I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to fix the number of subplots per figure, and create multiple figures -- but I'd also be open to alternative solutions that are "industry standard". I'll try to make the solution work for a multitude of figure types, not only `hist`, and appreciate approaches that dont rely on additional packages.

Here's a sample dataset, where -- for example -- I'd like to fix that no more than 4 groups are shown per figure.

```
sysuse educ99gdp
hist public, by(country)
```

I don't have any fixed idea on how exactly this should look, it should be scalable for 30-50 categorical values though. So, grouping the countries and showing multiple histograms in the same subplot works fine when there's only 10, not so fine when there is 30.

One suggested solution - but I'm happy to have it another way that is more Stata-ish - would be to have 3 separate figures, 4 subplots on each, and the last figure would have two empty slots.

Comment: The example doesn't make much sense by me. Said dataset has 10 observations for 10 countries, so a histogram shows one bar, each showing one value for each country. There are much better ways to show the data,  in a single bar or dot chart for example, without any loss of clarity.. ` graph dot (asis) public private, over(country, sort(1)) marker(1, ms(Oh)) marker(2, ms(+))` would be a start.

Comment: More crucially even, what you want instead is not clear. You could group countries into 4 and show pooled histograms. If that is what you want you just need to create  your own grouping variable first. If that is not what you want, please add detail on what you do want. EIther way, this is far from clear.

Comment: @NickCox I only looked quickly, but I didn't find an example dataset with many categorical values to demonstrate my situation. I'll update the question to make it clearer.

Comment: No clearer to me, sorry. There is no automated suboption to `by()` to show fewer panels. It's all in your hands to use a coarser grouping variable.

Comment: @NickCox You do understand what I'm trying to achieve, but don't know a way to do it "out of the box", right? Or is it literally still unclear?

Comment: You want fewer panels and as I have said twice you need an argument to -by()- that ensures such a result. What is unclear to me is what other solution you think there could possibly be.